# cURL SSL communication equivalent in Android

Tags: android, ssl, curl, ssl-certificate

I am porting an application which internally makes cURL calls to connect to a server securely. It uses downloaded certificate and private key file before making request to the server.

I have a "My_Private_key.pem" file containing RSA Private key, a "My_Certificate.pem" file containing the certificate server sent and a password with which "My_Private_key.pem" is encrypted. Now cURL has an option for setting SSLKey,SSLCertificate and Password.
Example

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, credentials->certfile);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, credentials->keyfile);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_KEYPASSWD, credentials->passwd);
```

Then cURL uses this information to request the server. I want to do a similar thing in Android. I have gone through many links which help me creating my own HttpClient which uses EasySSLSocketFactory,EasyX509TrustManager but i could not find a way to set these options in Android.

What is the equivalent way to do in Android ?

I am very new to SSL and so my question can be a little naive so please bear with it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a PKCS#12 file from your key and certificate, load it as a keystore and initialize HttpClient (or HttpsURLConnection) with it. For HttpClient you can use the [SSLSocketFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html) class to initialize the client with your key and certificate.

You can use something like this to create the PKCS#12 file:

$ openssl pkcs12 -export -in mycert.pem -inkey mykey.key -out mystore.pfx

Comment: My certificate  and key will be downladed at runtime . How can i create the PKCS#12 file at runtime ?

Comment: Shd i use this https://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/ee864337e77d30db?pli=1 for reference ?

Comment: Interesting. How would you get the password securely and make sure you  are getting the right key? If you are doing this at runtime, you don't need to create a PKCS#12 file, just import them into a KeyStore, so you can use to initialize HttpClient. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/KeyStore.html

Comment: Re the android-developers thread, yes, something like this. But you would load the key and certificate dynamically using http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/KeyStore.html#setKeyEntry(java.lang.String, java.security.Key, char[], java.security.cert.Certificate[])

Comment: The password to encrypt the private key PEM file is created locally on phone as the private key is of phone.Its not received from server.Sorry if i am incorrectly answering you. I will have a look at your links and update with the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me perfectly. 
I took it from a stackoverflow link but i cannot find that now. So posting the code

```
public void setHttpsClient(String password) {

        try {
            KeyStore mycert = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");

            byte[] pkcs12;

            //Load the PKCS file from database or file.
            pkcs12 = DataManager.getAuthP12Data();
            ByteArrayInputStream pkcs12BAIS = new ByteArrayInputStream(pkcs12);
            mycert.load(pkcs12BAIS, password.toCharArray());

            SSLSocketFactory sockfact = new SSLSocketFactory(mycert, null, null);

             sockfact.setHostnameVerifier(new StrictHostnameVerifier());

            // Done temporarily to accept all hosts
            //sockfact.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

            SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
            registry.register(new Scheme("https", sockfact, 443));

            BasicHttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(httpParameters, false);
            HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(httpParameters, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, _TIMEOUT);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, _TIMEOUT);

            ThreadSafeClientConnManager cm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(
                    httpParameters, registry);
            cm.closeExpiredConnections();
            cm.closeIdleConnections(3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

            _httpClient = new MyHttpClient(cm, httpParameters);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Call this above method before you start making your HTTPS calls